# Snake for 2 players - multithreading doesn't work

Tags: c

I'm trying to get into C "deeper" so I decided to write a game - Snake for 2 players.

Creating a "map", Snake structure, putting it into the "map" (using COORD) is not a problem, but I knew, I would stuck somewhere, so... here it is.

/* I created two functions called ruch() and ruch2() that both use _kbhit() and _getch() to move the s1 and s2 Snake structures (only "head" is already written, will take care of "tail" later).
The problem is that I want each Snake to move simultaneously in one of chosen direction (based on _getch()), so I tried to use a multithreading function from on of the guides, but it doesn't work.

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/psm6hm3p

Previosly, there was no function called ruch2() and it was merged with original ruch().
And here is original ruch(): http://pastebin.com/WXpPfK8H - so as you can see whenever user presses the key, one of the cases starts the loop (till next _getch()) - it works, but it's bugged - only one Snake is able to move continuously, because when one moves - second waits for _getch() and vice versa. It also doesn't allow other function in main() to run. */

function that is responsible for moving both snakes

```
void ruch(Snake *g){
while (_kbhit()){
    switch (_getch()){
    case lewo:
        if (g->y > 1){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 32);
                g->y--;
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 176);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch(g);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case prawo:
        if (g->y < width - 2){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 32);
                g->y++;
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 176);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch(g);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case gora:
        if (g->x > 1){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 32);
                g->x--;
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 176);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch(g);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case dol:
        if (g->x < height - 2){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 32);
                g->x++;
                putcharXY(g->x, g->y, 176);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch(g);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

```
void ruch2(Snake *h){
while (_kbhit()){
    switch (_getch()){
    case 'a':
        if (h->y>1){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 32);
                h->y--;
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 178);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch2(h);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'd':
        if (h->y<width - 2){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 32);
                h->y++;
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 178);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch2(h);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'w':
        if (h->x>1){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 32);
                h->x--;
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 178);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch2(h);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 's':
        if (h->x<height - 2){
            while (1){
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 32);
                h->x++;
                putcharXY(h->x, h->y, 178);
                Sleep(500);
                if (_getch()){
                    ruch2(h);
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

and

some lines of code that are responsible for multithreading that doesn't work:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadId1, ThreadId2;
HANDLE hHandles1, hHandles2;
hHandles1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ruch(&s1),
    0, 0, &ThreadId1);
hHandles2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ruch2(&s2),
    0, 0, &ThreadId2);
if (hHandles1 == NULL || hHandles2 == NULL)
{
    printf("Nieudane tworzenie watkow\n");
    exit(0);
}
//Oczekiwanie na zakończenie funkcji
WaitForSingleObject(hHandles1, INFINITE);
WaitForSingleObject(hHandles2, INFINITE);
```

tl;dr - Problem with multithreading

edit: some of the function's names are polish words, so ruch = move, zryj = food, Snake japko = food structure, rysuj = draw map once and "travel" on it via putcharXY (COORD)

Comment: For those of us not biting at the chance to click to an offsite link, are you saying you have two threads, both waiting for the *same* synchronous input, and each is robbing the other of its chance at the table?

Comment: Your post needs to contain a [mcve] **here**, in the question itself, and not in two separate links off-site. First, your question should be self-contained; using external links for major content means that if that link is unavailable for some reason your question has no value to future users here. Second, expecting us to leave this site and go elsewhere to figure out what you're asking is simply unreasonable. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem** - you should make it as easy for us as possible, and bouncing all over the place to read it isn't doing so. See [ask].

Comment: edited @WhozCraig

Comment: You clearly did not read the link I provided. I'll try again: Please provide a [mcve] (stressing **complete**).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good use case for threads.

Both of your threads are calling `_kbhit()` and `_getch()` periodically. This means they're effectively "fighting" over input -- when a key is pressed, whichever one manages to call `_getch()` first gets that key, and the other one gets nothing.

Rewrite your program to run as a single loop that handles both players. You don't need threads for this.